# Faulty conversion, std::string -> LPCSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a function Analyze_, that returns a std::string with some info in it, I 
want it in LPCSTR form though.
When I use c_str() like this, it works and l stores my information:

```
std::string s =  myClassInstance.Analyze_();
LPCSTR l      = s.c_str();
```

But when I write it shorter, like the following, I get a series of 'Ỳ's:

```
LPCSTR l = myClassInstance.Analyze_().c_str();
```

Is it calling c_str() before Analyze_()? I guess that should be impossible 
because it's a function, not a string.

I tried other solutions, such as directly converting it from the stringstream that generates the string and just return that, like so:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Bla blub...\n";
return ss.str().c_str();
```

But I have the same problem there. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a `const char*` to the internal buffer of the `std::string`. Chaining method calls like you're doing here `LPCSTR l = myClassInstance.Analyze_().c_str();` creates a temporary `std::string` (the return of `Analyze()`) and then returns the pointer to the internal buffer of that string. Then, the string is destroyed and you're left with a dangling pointer, Undefined Behaviour when trying to derefence. Just save the `std::string` if you want to use a pointer to it's buffer.

Comment: you were faster ;) but yeah as TL;DR: don't use the c_str()-ptr when the string object is not there anymore.